# How to reload an html page with no cache?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Im uploading advertisement images to a folder on a web server.  I have an html form  with a file upload that uses a javascript to display a preview of the selected image.  The problem I have is the image preview only works one time.  After submitting and coming back to the page to select another image there is no image preview for the selected image.

Ive tried using window.location.reload(true) in a function called with "on submit" in the html form.

```
<form id="userForm" action="upload1.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="doFull()">
```

Im building and testing may application in Safari browser

Here is the form and scripts Im using on admin_store1.html

```
   <div class="container">
   <form id="userForm" action="upload1.php" method="post"
   enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="doFull()"> 
   <label for="file" style="center">Filename:</label>
   <input type="file" name="file" id="file" align="center"
                onchange="readURL(this);"><br>

    <img id="blah" src="#" alt="no image selected" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" align="center">
    </form>
    </div>

<script>
        function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#blah')
                    .attr('src', e.target.result)
                    .width(150)
                    .height(200);
            };

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);


        }
    }
    </script>

<script>
    function doFull() {
    //do your actions here
    save_string_to_database("images/s1/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    window.location.reload(true);
    window.location = "/upload1.php"
</script>
```

Here is the upload1.php page

```
    <?php
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
      {
      echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
      }
    else
     {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "images/s1/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
     header("Location: site/admin_start.html");
    die();
     }
    ?>
```

I expect to return to admin_store1.html after uploading an image and to be able to see an image preview when an image is selected.

Comment: add a random or time based element as part of the query string `?foo=12345`  or `?foo='.time()` etc.  You can even base it off the filesize in the case of an image.